# How to add "common" functions to multiple XSLT files?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I've written the following code to get a `Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer` object that I can use to transform an XML document.  `TransformationXslt` is a string that contains the XSLT.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(TransformationXslt);
Saxon.Api.XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(document);
Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
Saxon.Api.XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(input);
Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.Load();
xsltTransformers.Add(transformation.Name, xsltTransformer);
return xsltTransformer;
```

Suppose that I have a dozen or more XSLT templates that I want to be able to call from *any* XSLT.  How can I make them available to the resulting `Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer` object.

Suppose I have something like this:

```
string commonXslt = "<xsl:param name="Use_This_In_Every_Xslt">Foo!</xsl:param>";
```

How can I make this "common" xslt available to the transformer?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way with XSLT to write stylesheet modules is not depending on the XSLT processor API, rather you put your code in stylesheet (e.g. `module1.xsl`) and then you include or import it in other stylesheets using `xsl:include` or `xsl:import`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#combining-modules for details. You would however need to make sure your module is a complete, well-formed XSLT document and not a single `xsl:param` element.

Of course if you have all XSLT only available in memory as strings then you would need to make sure the http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltCompiler.html#XmlResolver you set up for your XsltCompiler resolves a relative URL to load another module from a string.